# Microsoft Exchange contacts duplicating

Tags: contacts, exchange

Why are my Microsoft Exchange contacts joined/connected with "phone" contacts with the exact same information? I have tried removing the duplicate but when I call a person the "phone" contact is created again.

Comment: In addition to geffchang's answer below, you can always merge your duplicate contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide the Exchange contacts if you don't want to see them. In the Contacts app:

[image]